# Bindind to keys C++

Tags: c++, bind

Hello there I am a realative newbie when it comes to using different "commands" in order to achieve things so I was wondering if any of you know a way to bind a key to do a certain task anywhere in the programme ,so I would be able to display a function for example and after the display finishes the programme carries on normally like nothing happened and then that same key on any other push would still do the display . Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll want to look into 'keyboard accelerators' and check for some examples.

Comment: If you mean hotkeys, then you can use the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) function which is quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

Plain C++ does not have any concept of "key binding". The platform (e.g., the operating system) has this knowledge and it provides some libraries to handle it. So, you must provide more information about the operating system, or use a cross-platform library like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

Comment: I am currently trying to build the programme in Ubuntu but I want it to be able to run on Windows as well that's why I did not use a function like GetAsyncKeyState which is Windows only.